# how do I hide method implementation details

Tags: c#, oop

In c# String class they hide the details of all methods in the string class. For example, the "ToLower" method implementation is like follow.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Returns a copy of this string converted to lowercase.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// A string in lowercase.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority><PermissionSet><IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="UnmanagedCode"/></PermissionSet>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public string ToLower();
```

How can I do this also to my own class? and hide my implementation details from the class's user.

Comment: "This is called encapsulation" --- it is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assessment of the situation is incorrect.

I'm assuming you pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> ("Go to definition") in Visual Studio while you had `String.ToLower()` selected. This does *not* always display the source-code for the selected symbol - it will only display the source code if it is available on your system - otherwise it displays an outline of the containing type based on available metadata (i.e. the public type information declared in .NET assembly files: non-native .NET `.dll` and `.exe` files).

Confounding things, if you look at some other `String` methods using RedGate Reflector or other CIL disassembly tools then you'll see this, without any source disassembly:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical]
private extern String ReplaceInternal(Char oldChar, Char newChar);
```

This part: `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` means that there is no CIL implementation, instead it's implemented internally in the CLR (presumably in some high-performance C++ or x86 assembly code). However, this does not apply to `ToLower()`, which does actually have a CIL implementation (but it eventually calls into `TextInfo.InternalChangeCaseString` which is also `InternalCall`).

Regarding your own comments:

> This is called encapsulation.

No, this is not encapsulation. [Encapsulation in OOP refers to how a class has been designed to hide implementation details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) to OOP consumers (like how `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` does not reveal its internal `T[]` buffer). It is nothing to do [with obfuscating program source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).

> Now my question is how can I do this also to my own class?

You can't.

Of course, if you don't distribute the source-code of your program then other users in Visual Studio who also press <kbd>F12</kbd> will likewise see the same result as you: just the class outline - but nothing stops someone from disassembling it using a tool like Reflector, and CIL obfuscation (using tools like Dotfuscator) only go so far to protect your code.

Comment: This isn't even obfuscation. It's just writing a header file that shows only the declarations without the definitions. (Except that isn't a thing in C#.)